# Access variable inside the function ::TypeScript & Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, scope

I have a **c3.js** library which draws a chart inside my angular2 file. The drawing script is inside a function:

```
private draw() {

 let chart = c3.generate({
  bindto: '#chart',
  data: {
    columns: [
      ['data1', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250, 130, 50, 20, 10, 40, 15, 25, 390],
      ['data2', 50, 20, 10, 40, 15, 25, 542, 30, 200, 100, 333, 150, 250]
    ],
    type: "line"
  }   

});
```

}

**c3.js** library provides a possibility to change the type of the chart from `line` to `spline`, by using following function:

`chart.transform('spline');`

But unfortunately I dont have an access to this `chart` variable, since its inside the `draw()` function.

I want to put this `chart.transform('spline');` function inside a button, to let the user change it dynamically.

~**I need some way to make it work, any help highly appreciated!**

Comment: You can add chart as a field on the class you use it.

Comment: You have to use a service to do it, your function should be the method of a component, and you need to get the variable through a getter on your service.

Comment: @Sakuto If you would be so wise to make a full answer with some example, please?

Comment: if you define a component variable and then initialize that variable inside ngOnInit, you should be able to use it anywhere. In the case the chart is actually a component

Answer (score 0):

```
chart:any;

private draw() {

 this.chart = c3.generate({
  bindto: '#chart',
  data: {
    columns: [
      ['data1', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250, 130, 50, 20, 10, 40, 15, 25, 390],
      ['data2', 50, 20, 10, 40, 15, 25, 542, 30, 200, 100, 333, 150, 250]
    ],
    type: "line"
  }   

});
```

you can use  `this.chart` anywhere

Comment: Already tried this. Received an error: `ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: Cannot read property 'transform' of undefined`

Answer (score 0):

try to initialize chart :

```
chart: any = {};
```

then call it

```
this.chart.transform('spline');
```